# SESSION unable to Retain Values | Logical Error in PHP Code

Tags: php, session

AIM OF MY PROGRAM
1. 5-6 circles be shown on my site of blue color each.
2. Whenever, a circle is clicked it should turn RED or GREEN permanently.

Here is my Code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Let's see !</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
define("SIZE", 5);


for ( $i = 0 ; $i < SIZE ; $i++ ) //Initializes all Color Blocks to BLUE if not clicked
    {
        //If Image has been clicked, it takes a Color RED or GREEN
            if ( isset($_POST[$i."form"]) ) 
        {
            if($i % 2 == 0)
            $_SESSION[$i] = "green.jpg";
            else
            $_SESSION[$i] = "red.jpg";
        }
        else
        {   //to check if image was previously clicked.
            if ( $_SESSION[$i] == "green.jpg")
                $_SESSION[$i] = "green.jpg";

            elseif ( $_SESSION[$i] == "red.jpg")
                $_SESSION[$i] = "red.jpg";  
            else    //if never clicked it will be made blue.
                $_SESSION[$i] = "blue.jpg";  
        }
    }

for ( $i = 0 ; $i < SIZE ; $i++ )
{
?>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="image" width=120 src="<?php echo $_SESSION[$i]; ?>" name="mainin"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $i."form"; ?>" value="" /> 
</form>
<?php }
echo session_id(); //Sessions are working correctly. No issue with them.
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**What Happens in this program ?**
Whenever a circle, is clicked it turns to RED. When, the second circle is clicked, it turns to GREEN, and the first circle shows up as BLUE. Whereas, when the second circle is clicked, the first circle should show as red and second one as green.

As Far as i feel, there is a logical or conceptual error in this program. If somebody can tell me where i went wrong, i shall be greatful. I have been trying to figure this out for hours.

Comment: please paste your html form code as well.

Comment: Start with a simple `var_dump($_POST)` so that you can verify that why you think is being submitted *is* actually submitted. Add the output (view in browser-source) to the question.

Comment: The HTML form code is already present. Please scroll a little down.

Comment: @RohitTripathi ahh.. sorry.. i missed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$*SESSION's cannot begin with a numerical key, append them with something like circle*, e.g.:

```
$_SESSION['circle_'.$i]
```

Hope that helps. I tested it on my system and this fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks a tonne. I read one of the finest books on PHP, but nothing like this was mentioned. You are a real charm. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, I recommend turning your PHP Error reporting to a stricter setting, as my setting was displaying errors when trying to assign values to a numerical session. :-).

Comment: Okay. I added the following `error_reporting = E_ALL` to my php.ini file. I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: Awesome - I believe mines set to: `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`

Comment: Hey, i set it to `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`, but and switched to my original code. No errors were reported. Any idea about this ?

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the correct php.ini file? To find the config file location, use `<? phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17032/discussion-between-david-and-rohit-tripathi)

Answer (score 1):

Only one form gets submitted at a time. If you click on your first image, the code for the other images goes into the else branch ("to check if image was previously clicked") and the color is reset to blue. BTW: Only the "blue" line in said branch does anything at all, you can delete the rest. Also, you should check if the session field is empty before setting it to "blue".